# Query using firestore collectionGroup but cant get data from root collection

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my data structure]
[image: And nested collection]

I want to fetch learners enrolled in a specific subject.
the collectionGroup works

```
dbFire4 = Firebase.firestore
dbFire4.collectionGroup("ClassEnrolled")
    .whereEqualTo("classID", classID)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
     for (doc in documents)
            {
                val empData = doc.toObject(LearnerModel::class.java)
                learnerList.add(empData)
            }
            val mAdapter = LearnerAdapter(learnerList)
            recViewLearnerList.adapter = mAdapter
            recViewLearnerList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
     }
    .addOnFailureListener{e->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding data", e)
    }
```

But i cant seem to fetch the data from the root collection which is the learners info.

This what i want fetch.. The classID of the Learner and the information of the learner.

[image]

Comment: What is the value of ` classID` inside `.whereEqualTo("classID", classID)`? Have also tried with a hard-coded value? Does it work that way?

Comment: Thanks for the response..
the value is this
.whereEqualTo("classID", 2023-2024Diamond7-258074)

Comment: actually i have the answer by  fetching through subcollection, and then fetch database again using using another query.. a total of 2 queries, i just asked to find if there is a simpler way to do these.. in just 1 query, since they are connected from the root collection to the sub-collection

Comment: Yes, you can use just a single query, a `collectionGroup` query. Please edit y our question and add the content of your `LearnerModel` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single read operation only reads from a single collection, or a set of collection of the same name.

There is no API to read from the `ClassEnrolled` and the `Learners` parent document at the same time. You will need to perform separate read operations for those.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know we can fetch data from root collection to subcollection.. I just thought that I could fetch the data from subcollection to root. Now I know this is impossible.. Now i have to perform 2 queries for this.. Thank you so much for the enlightenment..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this would not be possible without making multiple queries to the database. One for grabbing all of the class documents, and then more to grab each of their parents.

This answer assumes the following structure (as derived from your question's screenshots):

```json
// Learners/$learnerId
{
  "learnerAffix": string,
  "learnerFirstName": string,
  "learnerLRN": string, // document ID
  "learnerLastName": string,
  /* ... */
}

// Learners/$learnerId/EnrolledClasses/$classID
{
  "classID": string // document ID
}
```

Looking at this query:

```
dbFire4.collectionGroup("ClassEnrolled")
    .whereEqualTo("classID", classID)
    .get()
```

The query finds all documents contained in collections named `"ClassEnrolled"` with the class ID specified in the query. To get the document that contains this class ID document, you need to get a reference to the path.

```
val learnerDocRef = doc
  .getReference()   // reference to the nested class document
  .getParent()      // reference to the nested EnrolledClasses collection
  .getParent()      // reference to the learner's information document
```

Once you have the path, you can go fetch each of those documents.

```
dbFire4.collectionGroup("ClassEnrolled")
    .whereEqualTo("classID", classID)
    .get()
    .onSuccessTask { qSnapshot -> 
        return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(
            qSnapshot.getDocuments()
                .map { it.getReference().getParent().getParent().get() }
        )
    }
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (doc in documents)
        {
            val empData = doc.toObject(LearnerModel::class.java)
            learnerList.add(empData)
        }
        val mAdapter = LearnerAdapter(learnerList)
        recViewLearnerList.adapter = mAdapter
        recViewLearnerList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    .addOnFailureListener{e->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding data", e)
    }
```